# Dell's Diagnostics say USBStatus Failure - what does it mean?

Tags: windows-10, usb, wake-up

When I run a diagnostic test on my 5 year old Dell Inspiron it says the following

[image]

I have been facing a small problem recently. I want to know if it's related to this.

I have wireless mouse with a USB receiver. I sleep my Laptop all the time, when I wake it up from sleep, the mouse works. But for the last month or so, every other time, the mouse doesn't work & I have to remove the USB receiver & connect it back for the mouse to start working.

These are my advanced Power USB settings

[image]

I don't think this has changed recently? What could be the problem?

I am running Windows 10. The wireless mouse is also Dell less than a year old & batteries also changed recently.

Comment: 1. Try disabling USB selective suspend, at least when plugged in. 2. If the USB truly *failed*, no deice would work in it at all, so I'd ignore the test results for now. The issue may have been caused by a Windows update. To see if there *is* a hardware issue, boot from a USB, e.g., with Windows RE or Ubuntu Live -- no need to install anything on the PC's drive. Let the computer sleep a few times, then see if the issue recurs. If not, then Windows OS is at fault; try SFC and DISM to repair, or reinstall Windows, keeping files.

Comment: Tried disabling USB selective suspend. Doesn't help